# @ - что это за оператор в php

Tags: php

```
/**
 * @package WordPress
```

Подскажите, где в документации можно найти про него информацию

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите пример кода, а этим оператором

Comment: ковыряю WP - там такая запись: @package WordPress

Comment: Ну вот и добавьте кусок интересующего вас кода в вопрос. Хотя бы строчек 5, чтобы был понятен контекст.

Comment: @Proshka это похоже на строчку с  DocBlock, это с комментария вы взяли получается

Comment: да, с коммента. Где покопать информацию в этом направлении?

Comment: Добавьте этот коммент в сам вопрос

Comment: Раз автор ленится, дописал сам по имеющейся инфе, щито поделать)

Comment: Спасибо, спешил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего это часть аннотации с DockBlock. 
Почитать про него можете в английской версии [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPDoc) или нашел ещё запись на русском в 
[блоге](http://everstudent.ru/blog/php/code-documention-docblock/).

Примерно вот так он выглядит:

```
/**
 * Название класса. Одна строчка.
 *
 * Подробное описание класса. Можете написать сколько угодно строчек.
 * Это не обязательная часть, но часто очень желательная.
 *
 * Вы также можете добавить тэги. Они пишутся так: @tag. tag - название тэга.
 * Каждый тэг несет какую-то смысловую нагрузку.
 *
 * @author Jason Lengstorf <jason.lengstorf@ennuidesign.com> - имя автора
 * @copyright 2010 Ennui Design
 * @license http://www.php.net/license/3_01.txt PHP License 3.01
 */
```

Comment: Да, все верно. Это не php-код, это DocBlock. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

из [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.errorcontrol.php):

> если он предшествует какому-либо выражению в PHP-коде, любые сообщения об ошибках, генерируемые этим выражением, будут проигнорированы.

Comment: @package WordPress - что здесь будет проигнорировано?

Comment: `@package WordPress` - это не php код

Comment: разобрался: в php - это оператор подавления ошибок, а в моем случае - это comment DocBlock. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Оператор `@` в PHP означает подавление ошибок (то есть, функция не будет выдавать Warning и Notice). Имейте в виду, работает он очень медленно.

Пример:

```
$page = @file_get_contents('http://example.com');
```